# How do I use Tokyo Cabinet with a .Net language?

Tags: .net, key-value, tokyo-cabinet

Is it possible to use Tokyo Cabinet with any of the .Net Languages, preferably VB10? How about Tokyo Tyrant? Preferably without going through LUA/Ruby or other wrappers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've just published a .NET wrapper for [Tokyo Tyrant on CodePlex](http://tokyotyrant.codeplex.com/). It supports the key/value interface as well as the table database mode. It also has a comprehensive example app that should get you started quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/). The only .NET wrapper I know of is [SharpCouch](http://code.google.com/p/couchbrowse/source/browse/trunk/SharpCouch/SharpCouch.cs), but you could also access it using the database's native RESTful HTTP API. I imagine there are a few other wrappers out there by now, but I don't know of any others off hand.